# can't create user on mysql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE USER ‘user’@’127.0.0.1’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘pass’;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘pass’' at line 1

Comment: Are you really using these funky quotes: `‘`? Use regular single quotes instead: `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `‘` with `'`:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```